# Chamisha Vachamishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred fifty-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting and relevant answers.*
- *Accept the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

Comment: you've asked 256 without closing 255.

Comment: @msh210 Could have sworn that I did. Oh, well. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.inner.org/parshah/genesis/lech_lecha/E68-0206.php

In Hebrew, the root of “river” (נהר ) is one of the 13 synonyms for “light.” It is also the root of the Aramaic translation of “light” in the beginning of creation. “And God saw the light to be good.” Numerically, both the word for “river” (**נהר = 255**) and “Euphrates” (פרת = 680) are multiples of “good” טוב (= 17).

Answer (score 1):

*Lag baomer* is the 255th day of a leap year in which *Cheshvan* and *Kislev* have 59 days between them.

Answer (score 1):

There are 255 words in the Torah reading of Shabbos Mincha, Monday & Thursday in Parshas Chukas.